# How can I refresh Media library in Android 6.0?

Tags: android, media

In Android4.4, can send broadcastreceiver ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE to force refresh media library, but it does't work in 5.0 or 6.0. When I add a mp3 file to my phone's foler and then the media library refresh default, but when I delete a mp3 file, it can't refresh normally.
`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`, this method also doesn't work.

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE + " > " + FILTER_SIZE);
    sb.append(" and "+MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " !=0");
    sb.append(" and " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + " > " + FILTER_DURATION);

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, proj_music, sb.toString(), null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_KEY);
```

These is the code I used to find all mp3 file. When user delete a mp3 file (not only by code, maybe use file manager), the Android media library can't refresh unless restart system. I wan't to force refresh media library. But `ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` doesn't work in android > 4.4, and `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`this code also doesn't work. The deleted mp3 file still in database record.

```
private void refresh1() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/kgmusic/download/";
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{path}, new String[]{"mp3/*"}, null);
}

private void refresh2() {

    mScanReceiver = new MyScanReceiver();

    IntentFilter intentfilter = new IntentFilter( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intentfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED);
    intentfilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED);
    registerReceiver(mScanReceiver, intentfilter);

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/kgmusic/download/";

    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path));
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,contentUri);
    sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}

private class MyScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_STARTED)) {
            System.out.println("scan start");
        } else if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED)) {
            System.out.println("scan finish");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _foler_ or _folder_?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this problem and i solved it this way.

As `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));`  is deprecated in API level 19(KITKAT 4.4) first i have to check whether is device is above API level 19 and if true then `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` method.

```
final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
if (isKitKat) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{"mp3/*"}, null);
} else {
    context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"
          + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I don't try to refresh to get image file,but mp3 file can't refresh normally.And I also use `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`.

Comment: `String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/download/";MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{path}, new String[]{"audio/*"}, null);`

Comment: try new String[]{"mp3/*"}

Comment: `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{path}, new String[]{"mp3/*"}, null);` can't refresh when I delete mp3 file,the deleted file still exists.

Comment: I don't use code to delete mp3 file,I go into file manager to delete the file directly.

Comment: i don't get it. can you explain in detail?

Comment: e,I sorry for my english.I mean I delete mp3 file use "Root Explorer" file manager,not by code.

Comment: i don't understand what you have mentioned in question is that MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() is not working it is way of refreshing media library programatically in code now you are saying i am deleting mp3 file there two are different

Comment: in your question please show code where you have used ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE?

Comment: please look at the question. @Rajesh

Comment: @David did you manage to solve this?
I am having the same problem with .mp3 files and Android 6.0. In my App, if i add new track, the Media Scanner doesnt show the new .mp3 track in its list, But if i check the FileExplorer it is very much there!
Neither does it show in WhatsApp Audio track list too! Any ideas?